# How to assign a name to every view in a storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

So I have an app where I use for the UI a storyboard with different views.
In the first view, there's an if statment when I push a button. It decides if the screen has to show the next ViewController or other. I already know how to do this with .xibs, but no with storyboards.

Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
.h
{
IBOutlet UIView *one;
IBOutlet UIView *two;
}

.m

-(IBAction)decideNextView:(id)sender{
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *NextView =[defaults objectForKey:@"TestDone"];
    if ([NextView isEqualToString:@""]) {
        self.view = one;
    }else if ([NextView isEqualToString:@"Done"]) {
        self.view = two;
    }else {
        self.view = one;
    }
}
```

When I run the app in my iPod Touch and I push the button that performs the `IBAction`, I get a black screen, but any error. Please help me!

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you are trying to do. Do you want to change the view based on what button the user pushes? Like View0 has 2 buttons, if Button1 is clicked it shows View1, if Button2 is clicked it shows View2?

Comment: No, you push one button; then the if is executed, and then the view will change the view one or view two.

Comment: Ah...that makes more sense now. There are a few ways to do what you want to do, depending on your UI goals. Are `view1` and `view2` going to take over the entire screen? If you want to take over the entire screen the best way to do it would be to make new view controllers for `view1` and for `view2`. Then you can drag out a segue and then you can call it in your conditional statement: `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]`. If it is just part of the screen, you might try the `hidden` property. Like `self.view1.hidden = YES;` when you load your view and then change to `NO` in the if/else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are supposed to access view elements in code is with the "Tag" item in the attributes inspector.  The best way to do this is to set it to a number and then do `#define kView1 0` so in code you don't need to remember what number you assigned to view1, you just use the constant.

[image: Tag property]

Where it says `Tag` here, you can set that to any number for each item in your storyboard or xib. Then in code you can say something like:

```
#define NAME_TAG 0
UIView *nameView = [self.view viewWithTag:NAME_TAG];
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to Objective-C and really young (16), so, could you explain your answer a little more? With just a little more I will be able to find the solution in the internet by myself. Thank you Mike.

Comment: Okay, I've used your code, and first of all, thank you for the tag information, I didn't know what it was for! Changing topic, I have used this code:                                                #define NAME_TAG 0                                               UIView *nameView = [self.view viewWithTag:NAME_TAG];
self.view = nameView;                                                     I thought that it would work, but I get a black screen when I run the app and I push the button. Any ideas Mike?